# How to use ViewChild in angular 2?

Tags: angular

in Angular 2 in a header component I have signup button that if click on it a modal dialog opens. I have made its method and the other things. And in main page that it is a separate component if I click on a button(it's name is continue) I want that modal dialog open exactly when I click on signup button in header. 
I try to use @ViewChild method:
this is header html:

```
<a class="button" type="button" (click)="showDialog()" >sign up</a>
```

and this is header ts:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: 'header-component',
templateUrl: './header.component.html',
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
display: boolean = false;
showDialog() {
this.display = true;
}
```

and this is that button use in another component:

```
<button [disabled]="!propertyForm.form.valid"
                      (click)="onSubmit($event)" type="submit">continue</button>
```

and the component is:

```
import {Component, Input, ViewChild,ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import {HeaderComponent} from "./header.component";
@Component({
templateUrl:'./add-property.html',
providers: [DataService, Amlak],
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
moduleId:module.id
})
export class AddPropertyComponent {
@ViewChild(HeaderComponent)
private headerComponent: HeaderComponent;
onSubmit($event) {
this.headerComponent.display=true;
 }
}
```

but it sends this error: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined

thank you for your helping in a simple and easiest way.

Comment: As Sharikov pointed out, you need an `@Component` decorator with html or html reference. I wonder what the html looks like too. Do you have the `HeaderComponent` inside the tag of your `AddPropertyComponent` ?

Comment: @bvdb +1 for full code of both components.

Comment: Next time don't try to minify your code please :)

Comment: Please add html code where you use these two component. Is "another component" parent of the `HeaderComponent`? If not then you'll keep getting this `undefined` error.

Comment: read [Exploring Angular DOM manipulation techniques using ViewContainerRef](https://blog.angularindepth.com/exploring-angular-dom-abstractions-80b3ebcfc02)